# How to send serial command via Screen via the command line

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to use a usb-to-rs232 adapter to send a serial command to a device connected to the rs232 port.  When I login into screen using `screen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600` and then enter my command from within the screen program, I get the expected response.

What I'm now trying to do is send a single serial command via a command line, but can't get my syntax quite right.

Here's an example of what I'm trying:

```
screen -dmS -p 0 /dev/cu.usbserial 9600 "MVUP"
```

...where MVUP with a carrier return is all I'm needing to send.  I don't need to read a response back.  Environment is OS X 10.7 and using the default bash shell.

Comment: man screen: -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts. The other point is the -p 0 (from man ->) The command will not be executed if the specified  window could not be found. So that could not works if it is not create once. Maybe you could try `-d -mS -p 0` or just `-d -mS`

Comment: or `-mS -p 0 -d` to detached immediately after create

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the space!

```
screen -dmS -p 0 /dev/cu.usbserial 9600 "MVUP"
```

but

```
screen -dmS -p0 /dev/cu.usbserial 9600 "MVUP"
```

works fine on my BBB

then to attach

```
screen -rmS -p0 /dev/cu.usbserial 9600 "MVUP"



aurelien@snowball:~$ sudo screen -rmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
[remote detached from 2845.-p0]
aurelien@snowball:~$ sudo screen -dmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
aurelien@snowball:~$ sudo screen -rmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
There are several suitable screens on:
        2861.-p0        (04/02/2016 04:10:25 PM)        (Detached)
        2845.-p0        (04/02/2016 04:10:07 PM)        (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
aurelien@snowball:~$ sudo screen -dmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
aurelien@snowball:~$ sudo screen -rmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
There are several suitable screens on:
        2971.-p0        (04/02/2016 04:13:09 PM)        (Detached)
        2861.-p0        (04/02/2016 04:10:25 PM)        (Detached)
        2845.-p0        (04/02/2016 04:10:07 PM)        (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
```

To attach you need to specify the number

```
sudo screen -rmS **2845** -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

or give them different name withe -p option -p0 -1 to have not the trouble like in the example of different screen all named 0! That will offer you a simple re-attach way

```
sudo screen -dmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
sudo screen -rmS -p0 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200

sudo screen -dmS -p1 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
sudo screen -rmS -p1 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200

sudo screen -dmS -p2 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
sudo screen -rmS -p2 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

...

Comment: Thanks for the help--unfortunately, it's still not working.  I'm now wondering whether or not a carriage return is being sent after the "MVUP"?  I've also tried "MVUP\r".  Anyone know how what screen defaults to or how to insert the return?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've started a session, then sent data to it using `stuff` with `\n` for newline:

```
screen -d -m -S myscreen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600
screen -S myscreen -X stuff 'MVUP\n'
```